# Python3 __pycache__ generating even if PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

Tags: python, python-3.x, capistrano

I would like to ask if there is another way to disable creation of `__pycache__` in the server.

My problem is it keeps generating even if I already set environment variable to `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`

I want to disable `__pycache__` because I only keep 5 releases in deployment. This cache is preventing the deletion of the 6th release because the cache is owned by root and can only be deleted through sudo.

I am using capistrano for deployment.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: Did you `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`? Merely setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in your shell is insufficient.

Comment: @BallpointBen I exported it. i also added it on `/etc/environment` and when I do `printenv PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` it shows that it is `1` in both my deploy_user and root user.

Comment: Hello everyone, I already resolved this issue. `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` works. The generation of `pycache` folder is in the docker (I used docker as well). What I did is inside the docker, I have this `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` So it solved the issue. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I already resolved this issue. `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` works. The generation of `pycache` folder is in the docker (I used docker as well). What I did is inside the docker, I have this `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` So it solved the issue. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 17):

You can also disable cache usage in the Python code via [sys.dont_write_bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.dont_write_bytecode):

```
import sys

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

import first_module
from second_module import MyClass
...
```

**Important:** You have to put these lines *before* each other import of your modules, because the creation of the cache file is triggered by the import statement.

Comment: Does not work. Tried in Python 3.9.6

Comment: @Nav: You have to put these lines _before_ all other imports of your modules. Please see my note. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio Code users: if the setting: `python.testing.pytestEnabled` is true, Visual Studio Code seems to ignore `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` and generates `__pycache__` at some time such as saving file.