# Can Python scripts be unable to access the module cache?

Tags: python, caching, conda, python-import

I'm having difficulty getting my python module imports to be quick. They should be near-instantaneous after the first import due to caching right? But every import is about the same time for me.

I used this script (test_import_times.py) to check import times:

```
import time
print('Start')

time0 = time.time()
import pandas
print(f'Time to import pandas: {time.time() - time0}')
```

I stored this script in two locations:

1. My network drive (P:)
2. local drive (C:)

I'm using Citrix Workspace by the way. I also created two conda-managed virtual environments:

1. On the network drive (P:\...\network_environment)
2. One on the local drive (C:\...\network_environment_clone)

Both virtual environments are identical and use Python 3.9.10 and pandas 1.4.1.

First, I used anaconda prompt to activate the environments, open the environment, and run python. Then I wrote a function called test_import_times() that did the same thing as test_import_times.py and ran it at that anaconda prompt command line. Second, I ran the code stored in the P: drive from both the P: and C: drive environments. Finally, I ran the code stored in the C: drive from both the P: and C: drive environments. I timed them and have placed the results below:

| P:...\network_environment | C:...\network_environment_clone |
| --- | --- |
| Directly in anaconda prompt | Directly in anaconda prompt |
| 1: Pandas = 110.10 secs, 2: Pandas = 0.0 secs | 1: Pandas = 22.89 secs, 2: Pandas = 0.0 secs |

| P:\Documents...\test_import_times.py | P:\Documents...\test_import_times.py |
| --- | --- |
| 1: Pandas = 102 secs, 2: Pandas = 96 secs | 1: Pandas = 21 secs, 2: Pandas = 22 secs |

| C:\Documents...\test_import_times.py | C:\Documents...\test_import_times.py |
| --- | --- |
| 1: Pandas = 103 secs, 2: Pandas = 97 secs | 1: Pandas = 18 secs, 2: Pandas = 19 secs |

The C:\ drive code has a **pycache** folder, but it's not being populated. The P:\drive code does not have a **pycache** folder.

I have tried searching for **pycache**, but have not had any success. Also, I have a jup369 env that's on my C:\ drive (it came with my Miniconda install). I opened this through Spyder, set the environment to be the default, and wrote the same script (placed in the C:\ drive). This time, the second import time was 0.0 secs.

I also used

```
conda info
```

to check what the package cache is for both the P:\ drive and C:\ drive environments. Both environments have the same package cache paths, with each environment having 3 paths, all of them in the C:\ drive. Is this where modules should be cached?

Why are the import times not lower on the second run of test_import_times.py?

And why did writing and running test_import_times at the anaconda prompt command line cause the second run to be 0.0 secs for both environments?

Was my script unable to access the python module cache?

Comment: @merv My apologies for the confusion. I am using Conda to create virtual environments. I was using venv to refer to that. I've made rewritten those parts of the post.

Comment: On my system (using venv) the `__pycache__` folders are located in `site_packages` inside the module folder, i.e. `.venv/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__` but conda my differ.

Comment: Also yes it can be disabled - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752302/python3-pycache-generating-even-if-pythondontwritebytecode-1 - although what you're seeing seems to imply that it's doing this automatically based don't the fact that P is a network share.